# Field Maps on iPad: Editing .mmpk features

Tags: arcgis-field-maps, mobile-map-package

I have an orthophoto raster and two features that I saved as a "Mobile Map Package" (.mmpk) in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.6 (by going to Share>Mobile Map).

I then added (sideloaded) the .mmpk file to the Field Maps app on my iPad. It opens fine.

I would like to now edit the features. but the blue "+" icon is missing, suggesting I am not allowed to edit any features. I have read about "[workarounds](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-unable-to-edit-features-in-arcgis-field-maps-000028650)" for what to do when the blue plus icon isn't there but this involves editing the feature on arcgis online...but the feature isn't there because it was sideloaded. Even if I upload the .mmpk to arcGIS Online, I can't change settings for features inside the .mmpk.

Any ideas about what to do to edit features sideloaded onto the app?

Note that I won't have internet where I'll be doing fieldwork next month (and I'll be creating and sideloading new .mmpk files to my ipad each day without internet) but I can't even figure this out with internet access.

[image: Screenshot of the sideloaded .mmpk using my Mac]

[image: Screenshot of Field Maps without a blue plus icon]